# @uppy/react invalid prop type when refactoring ModalDashboard to functional component

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use uppy-react as a stateless functional component which I then want to use in my container-components. The SFC is like so:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Uppy from '@uppy/core'
import { DashboardModal } from '@uppy/react'
import '../style.css';
import ButtonForm from '../Templates/Button';

const FileUpoad = (uppy) => {
return (
    <div className="container h-100">
    <DashboardModal
        uppy={uppy}
        hideUploadButton={true}
        open={uppy.open}
        onRequestClose={uppy.onRequestClose}
        plugins={[uppy.WebcamId]}
        closeModalOnClickOutside
    />
    </div>
 );
}

export default FileUpoad;
```

And then in the container-component:

```
import FileUpoad from '../Templates/FileUpload';
import Uppy from '@uppy/core'
import Webcam from '@uppy/webcam';

const uppy = new Uppy();

class Container extends Component {
state = {
    modalOpen: false,
}

handleModalOpen = () => {
 this.setState({
   modalOpen: true
 })
}

handleModalClose = () => {
    this.setState({
      modalOpen: false
    })
}

componentDidMount() {
  uppy.use(Webcam, {id: 'myWebcam'});
}

render(){
  <form>
    <ButtonForm
    name='fileUpload'
    onClick={this.handleModalOpen}
    type='button'
    className= 'btn btn-primary btn-block'
    content='Add Picture'
    />
    <FileUpoad
    open={this.state.modalOpen}
    onRequestClose={this.handleModalClose}
    WebcamId = 'myWebcam'
    uppy = {uppy}
    />
  </form>
```

When I run this code i get an error of:

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `uppy` of type `Object` supplied to `DashboardModal`, expected instance of `Uppy`.

I got it working with a strange workaround in which i created a second uppy instance (uppy2) in the stateless functional component and pass this into the DashoardModal, but this doesn´t feel right. How can i pass in the uppy instance as a prop from the container compoment so that i can really reuse the functional component? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `uppy.uppy`, like this:

```js
const FileUpoad = (uppy) => {
return (
    <div className="container h-100">
    <DashboardModal
        uppy={uppy.uppy}
        hideUploadButton={true}
        open={uppy.open}
        onRequestClose={uppy.onRequestClose}
        plugins={[uppy.WebcamId]}
        closeModalOnClickOutside
    />
    </div>
 );
}
```

Btw, using `props` instead of `uppy` for the parameter name would be better, even though it's completely arbitrary. For example:

```js
const FileUpoad = props => {
return (
    <div className="container h-100">
    <DashboardModal
        uppy={props.uppy}
        hideUploadButton={true}
        open={props.open}
        onRequestClose={props.onRequestClose}
        plugins={[props.WebcamId]}
        closeModalOnClickOutside
    />
    </div>
 );
}
```

You also can destructure the `props` like so:

```js
const FileUpoad = ({uppy, open, onRequestClose, WebcamId}) => {
return (
    <div className="container h-100">
    <DashboardModal
        uppy={uppy}
        hideUploadButton={true}
        open={open}
        onRequestClose={onRequestClose}
        plugins={[WebcamId]}
        closeModalOnClickOutside
    />
    </div>
 );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that got me half the way, but i am now struggeling with the webcam plugin, which does not get recognized. When i see the Uppy Object in the browser console it is there under plugins, but it does not get displayed in the ModalDashbaord.